# Does the layout or the view get loaded first in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've read somewhere that in ASP.NET MVC, the view gets "loaded" before the layout (the view logic gets applied before the layout logic). So I was wondering what's the real answer here, and is there a way to check this?

Comment: Hm, maybe I phrased it wrongly, I thought, which logic gets executed first.

Comment: What "view logic" and "layout logic" are you referring to _exactly_? It might help to explain what kind of answers you're looking for and how they will influence what you do next.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean what view get rendered in which order you can simply add debug statements to the views to find out.  For example:

_Layout.cshtml

```
    @{ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pre-RenderBody()");}
    @RenderBody()
    @{ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Post-RenderBody()");}
```

index.cshtml

```
@{ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index.cshtml:start");}
<div>Home Page</div>
@{ System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index.cshtml:end");}
```

Show ouput from: [Debug]:

> index.cshtml:start
>
> index.cshtml:end
>
> Pre-RenderBody()
>
> Post-RenderBody()

So the index.cshtml is executed first.  Then the layout, and the content is inserted (not really the right term as it's actually appended to the stream/string/stringbuilder prior to everything after `@RenderBody()`).

Answer (score -2):

The server returns whole HTML rendered from the view and layout.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that the layout logic gets loaded "first." For example, I have logic in my _layout that states:

```
@if (User.isAdmin)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Index","Admin")
}
```

Saying that if the users role is admin then allow them to view/click the settings button. So the layout logic would have to load "first."